# Heroku throws error on db:migrate rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When i'm trying to throw the `heroku run rake db:migrate` as it was said in RoR tutorial by Michael Hartl it throws me the following:

```
Running rake db:migrate on shielded-reaches-4728... up, run.2183
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method 'configure' for #<SampleApp::Application:0x007efe8ced6138>
/app/config/environments/production.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in 'require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in 'block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in 'load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in 'require'
..
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What can I do?

UPDATE:
This is my *production.rb* file:

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = true

  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_assets = false

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = false

  config.assets.digest = true

  config.log_level = :info

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Comment: Please show the first few lines of your `/app/config/environments/production.rb` file.

Comment: `Rails.application.configure do`

Comment: could you please add your `environments/production.rb` to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got something like this

```
...

module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

...
```

in your `application.rb` file. In which case, in your `production.rb` file, you need to change

```
Rails.application.configure
```

to

```
SampleApp::Application.configure
```